# Show output textarea with line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, regex, textarea

I'm trying to display the contents of a textarea, including any line breaks.

```
  var text =  document.getElementById("textInput").value    ;    
  text = text.replace(/[\n|\r\n]/g,"<br />");
  document.getElementById("voorwoord-voorbeeld-tekst-links").firstChild.nodeValue = text;
```

The replace works fine but it displays: 
      dfsdsf< br />s< br />df< br />sdf< br /> instead of breaks

How can I fix this? I've searched the whole web but can't find it..

Comment: Really, the whole web? **...**

Comment: @gdoron, the whole spiderweb in his bookshelf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the innerHTML of the element instead:

```
document.getElementById("voorwoord-voorbeeld-tekst-links").firstChild.innerHTML = text;
```